# Server App Version 5.3.1 won't take password

Tags: macos, password, server.app

My server app (OS X Sierra) will not take the admin password despite confirming that the password is correct when doing other administrative tasks. I have read that the Server App can 'just die' after the first install and I also read that you can enter `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.servermgrd.plist` in Terminal to load it, but that file is no longer located there (It moved in version 4)

I can't administer the server (I need to set up multiple share points) because it won't allow me in.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: No answers to this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Server that can run on your OS. You can try to repromote Server, by closing the app, moving it (the Server.app in /Applications) to the trash and waiting for the "Server Removal Detected" dialog to come up. After that you move it back to /Applications and launch it. It should ask you if you want to update Server on this machine. Update and see if that solves your problem.